# HQL does not like plus character

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

1. HQL parse `DATEADD(m,-1,GETDATE())` as `DATEADD(m,-1,GETDATE())`
2. HQL parse `DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())` as `DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())`
3. HQL parse `DATEADD(d,+1,GETDATE())` as `DATEADD(d)`
4. HQL parse `DATEADD(h,+23,GETDATE())` as `DATEADD(h)`

So I'm inclined to think that HQL doesn't like `+` character. Could you please suggest solution?

*P.S.* `DATEADD(d,+1,GETDATE())` works fine in SQL console.

Comment: You may have to use native sql query instead of HQL?

Comment: @OldProgrammer As option, but that's a bad practice. I believe HQL can parse that query (escape plus character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL is not SQL.

In particular the grammar of HQL is different of grammar of SQL.

I didn't found the formal grammar for HQL, but it is possible that for HQL the expression +1 is not correct.

In this case you can:

- Use native SQL instead of HQL
- Write 1 instead of +1 and continue using HQL